# .net decompiler that allows renaming fields

Tags: c#, .net, decompiling

I recently again came across a situation where I had to decompile an old assembly to see what it was really doing, we all know this problem...

Normally I do it with ILSpy after the redgate one became non-free.
However in the assembly I am currently working on, all the fields etc have really bland names to the point where they are all just string1, string 2, etc.

I whish I could just rename those fields to ease reading and keep my sanity. Code does not have to be able to re-compile. Or maybe not rename the fields themselfes but display something like a sticky comment next to them?

The only tool I know that could do this is Dis# but it has a really ugly gui and is paid, a free alternative would be awesome.

Comment: Why don't you just save it and edit it with a text editor?  Also, I use DotPeek.

Comment: Because thats like disassembling your car and shipping it and reassembling it where you wanted to drive to

Comment: Sometimes I really hate this close reason. As you see below, an experienced user pointed out two tools that we would have otherwise not known about.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: yeah I have to second. Reflexil is more or less exactly what I have been looking for and was not able to find on my own. Also this there a more suitable stackexchange site to ask for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reflexil](http://reflexil.net/) can do this. I have used it in the past with .NET Reflector, and I am happy to see on its web site that it can now also function with the free-of-charge [Telerik JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx).